# serialization/deserialization using json in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to serialize and deserialize from class object to json using json package. After looking into some documentation succeeded in serializing the simple class object but, when trying out with complex class am not able to deserialize the objects.

these are my classes:

```
 class FirstStandard:
    def __init__(self, student=None):
        self.students = []
        if student:
            self.students.append(student.__dict__)

    def toJson(self):
        return vars(self)

    def update(self, student):
        if student:
           self.students.append(student.__dict__)

class Student:
    def __init__(self, sid, fName, lName, fee):
        self.sid = sid
        self.fName = fName
        self.lName = lName
        self.fee = fee
```

This the code am trying with:

```
def student_hook(stu_dict):
    return FirstStandard(stu_dict['students'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Student(10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 12345)
    studs = FirstStandard(s)
    s1 = Student(11, 'AAA', 'BBB', 99999)
    studs.update(s1)

    # serialization
    message = json.dumps(studs.toJson())
    print(message)

    # deserialization
    x = json.loads(message, object_hook=student_hook)
    print(x.students)
```

When deserialising the students using the hook am expecting the entire students list should be present but, am receiving student object instead.

How this hook should be modified to get the json deserialised into my class object?

Comment: the error was in the hook method. Key error 'students' as the hook method receiving the student dict instead students dict

Comment: Ideally, you would not alter your class design at all to support serialization. You would just write the serializer code, most likely using a subclass of json.JSONEncoder and json.JSONDecoder. But it's late -- I'll try to get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: the problem with your student_hook is that it just gets one student object. It needs to return Student(**stu_dict), but it doesn't know that a list represents a FirstClass, and even if this did what you want, FirstClass can't handle multiple students in the constructor anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in different ways to change the hook method to construct the FirstStandard class object and at last succeeded in doing it by changing the hook method and adding one more method to the FirstStandard class. We can change hook method code to handle any complex objects.

Here is the entire code for it.

```
import json


class FirstStandard:
    def __init__(self, student=[]):
        self.students = []
        for i in range(len(student)):
            self.students.append(student[i].__dict__)

    def toJson(self):
        return vars(self)

    def append_as_dict(self, student):
        if student:
            self.students.append(student.__dict__)

    def append_as_class(self, student):
        if student:
            self.students.append(student)


class Student:
    def __init__(self, sid, fName, lName, fee):
        self.sid = sid
        self.fName = fName
        self.lName = lName
        self.fee = fee


def student_hook(stu_dict):
    sid = stu_dict.get('sid', 0)
    fName = stu_dict.get('fName', '')
    lName = stu_dict.get('lName', '')
    fee = stu_dict.get('fee', 0)
    if sid > 0:
        student = Student(sid, fName, lName, fee)
        first_standard.append_as_class(student)
    return first_standard


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global first_standard
    first_standard = FirstStandard()
    
    # Object creation
    s = Student(10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 12345)
    studs = FirstStandard([s])
    s1 = Student(10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 12345)
    studs.append_as_dict(s1)

    # serialization
    message = json.dumps(studs.toJson())
    print(message)

    # deserialization
    x = json.loads(message, object_hook=student_hook)
    for i in range(len(x.students)):
        print(x.students[i].sid)
        print(x.students[i].fName)
        print(x.students[i].lName)
        print(x.students[i].fee)
```

Comment: I'd advise against using side effects on a global object to make your json.loads work. The next time you load students, it will get a copy of the previous call, which hypothetically could give you data from a completely different FirstStandard. Also never use [] as a default argument.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to let your data class just do its job, and separate out the json code to encoder/decoder classes.

You went to all the trouble to define a Student class, so you really should use it, not the underlying python dict, unless you thought you had to for serialization? But no you don't have to do that.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders

I understand that documentation is not very readable, but here's an implementation. Since I'm storing FirstClass as just a list of students, that means I know all the json objects must be students, so we can just use an object hook.

```
import json

class FirstStandard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.students = []

    def add_student(self, student):
        if student:
            self.students.append(student)

class Student:
    def __init__(self, student_id, first_name, last_name, fee):
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.fee = fee

    def __repr__(self):
        """ so we can print the students """
        return f'<Student {self.student_id}: {self.first_name} {self.last_name}>'

def student_hook(student_info: dict):
    """ when json encounters a dictionary, assume it is a Student """
    return Student(**student_info)
    
class StudentsJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """ this contains the logic to convert each of your classes to json """
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, FirstStandard):
            return obj.students
        if isinstance(obj, Student):
            return obj.__dict__
        return super().default(obj)

class StudentsJsonDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    """this decoder understands our encoder
    a list is a FirstClass
    an object is a Student"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(object_hook=student_hook)

    def default(self, s):
        o = super().decode(s)
        if isinstance(o, list):
            result = FirstStandard()
            for student_info in o:
                result.add_student(Student(**student_info))
            return result
        return o
            
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    students = FirstStandard()
    students.add_student(Student(10, 'ABC', 'XYZ', 12345))
    students.add_student(Student(11, 'AAA', 'BBB', 99999))
    print('The starting students data:', students.students)

    # serialization
    message = json.dumps(students, cls=StudentsJsonEncoder)
    print(message)

    # deserialization
    x = json.loads(message, cls=StudentsJsonDecoder)
    print('We read this from the json:', students.students)
```

I am not really comfortable using __dict__ in the serialization, because things might change in the class, and a more complex class could have internal python details. In my production code, the class to be serialized will have a for_json member (which returns the dict that I actually want in json), and sometimes a classmethod create_from_json. This avoids fragility if the class changes, and gives me control of what actually goes into the json. But the class method doesn't have any json parsing responsibilities, it just gives/takes the arguments relevant to the class.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution:

To properly deserialize the JSON into your `FirstStandard` class object, you need to modify the `student_hook` function to create a `FirstStandard` object and populate its `students` list with the deserialized student dictionaries. Here's how you can modify the `student_hook` function:

```py
def student_hook(studs_dict):
    students = studs_dict.get('students', [])
    first_standard = FirstStandard()
    for student_dict in students:
        student = Student(student_dict['sid'], student_dict['fName'], student_dict['lName'], student_dict['fee'])
        first_standard.update(student)
    return first_standard
```

Replace the existing `student_hook` with the above code, and the deserialization should work as expected. This modified `student_hook` function extracts the list of student dictionaries from the JSON and iterates through each dictionary, creating `Student` objects and adding them to the `FirstStandard` object using the `update` method.

Comment: I mentioned that in the hook method am getting the student not FirstClass object as json. This code will definitely throws an error as there are no students in the json.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, justyce jaelen!

Your 7 answers so far appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). *Six* of those seven have comments from users indicating issues with the answer, which demonstrates why [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!